# Filter for strings in Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a better way than this to filter for strings in a Pandas series?

Here's what I came up with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,'cat','hat','mat'], 'b': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] })
```

Original:

```
a   b
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   3
3   4   4
4   cat 5
5   hat 6
6   mat 7

df = df[df['a'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
```

Result:

```
a   b
4   cat 5
5   hat 6
6   mat 7
```

However, this syntax seems verbose. Is there something of the form? :

```
df[df['a'].is_type(str)]
```

EDIT: I'm interested in checking for type, not content. So, for example, I would like to include `'12345'` and exclude `12345`.

Comment: Does, `df[df.a.apply(type) == str]` work?

Comment: Yes - this is a good idea, definitely more concise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will recommend `to_numeric`

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df.a,errors='coerce').isna()]
Out[246]: 
     a  b
4  cat  5
5  hat  6
6  mat  7
```

If you consider the situation mentioned in comment by zero

```
df[df.a.map(lambda x : type(x).__name__)=='str']
Out[257]: 
     a  b
4  cat  5
5  hat  6
6  mat  7
```

Comment: Does the OP want to filter `'1'` string? This will filter it out, I'm not sure, what OP wants.

Comment: No, I'm interested in checking for type, not content. So, I would like to include `'12345'` and exclude `12345`. I'll edit the question to explain this.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try:

```
df[df.a.str.isalpha() == True]
```

Out:

```
     a  b
4  cat  5
5  hat  6
6  mat  7
```

Comment: try isallnum() == True
It accounts for strings like '123'